# Can linux command comm handle UTF-8 encoded text files?

Tags: linux, diff, character-encoding, unicode, comm

I want to compare two UTF-8 encoded text file. Can Linux command diff and comm handle these encoding?

Comment: Note it is not Linux that does it. The kernel does not get involved with these matters. It is the Gnu tools that do it (If you are running a Linux based Unix system, then it will be Gnu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not?

2 text files in Russian

```
$ file -i test1.txt test2.txt                                                                                                                                                    
test1.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8                                                                                                                                                                               
test2.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8

$ cat test1.txt                                                                                                                                                                  
Привет                     

$ cat test2.txt                                                                                                                                                                  
Добрый день                                                                                                                                                                                                        

$ diff test1.txt test2.txt                                                                                                                                                       
1c1                                                                                                                                                                                                                
< Привет                                                                                                                                                                                                           
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> Добрый день
```

Comment: How was this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **-i** parameter to force file to **print information about the encoding**

I created two files containing some caracters

One encoded in **utf-8** and one encoded in **iso-8859-1**

```
$ file -i *
file1: text/plain; charset=utf-8
file2: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: I think they were asking about the `diff` and `comm` commands, not `file`